# Emacs C++ Mode: Highlighting Casts and Sizeof

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I am using the standard (shipped) Emacs C++ mode but I have a slight itch that I am looking to get scratched. How would I go about properly highlighting the types inside of a *sizeof* and the *casts* in C++?

For example:

1. **A Cast**

   `Type * pointer = reinterpret_cast <Type *> (original);`
2. **Sizeof**

   `std::cout << sizeof (Type) << "\n";`

Comment: what do you mean by "properly highlighting"?  Do you want the typename highlighted the same way as the typename when declaring a variable, or this there some other more "proper" way you would like it highlighted?

Comment: I want the typename to be highlighted as when declaring a variable, yes.

Comment: Given that, in `sizeof(X)`, it is entirely context-dependent whether X is a type or a variable, how accurate do you want it to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these expressions to your `.emacs`, or evaluate them with `M-:`.

**Sizeof** (that's the easier of the two cases)

The regex highlights any combination (indicated by the bracket expression `[...]`; regarding syntax, please see the note below) of alphanumeric, whitespace and asterisk within parentheses and preceded by `sizeof`.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
  '(("\\<sizeof[[:space:]]*(\\([[:alnum:][:space:]*]+\\))"
  1 font-lock-type-face t)))
```

The number `1` tells emacs to only highlight the first subexpression (marked by `\\(...\\)`) using the face `font-lock-type-face`; `t` means overriding any previous highlighting.

You can see and change the available faces with `M-x customize group [RET] font-lock-faces [RET]`.

**C++ style casts**

I'm not sure which typename you want to be highlighted – the “original” or the one to cast into.  This highlighter marks both:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
  '(("\\<[[:alnum:]]+_cast[[:space:]]*<\\([[:alnum:][:space:]*]+\\)>[[:space:]]*(\\([[:alnum:][:space:]*]+\\))"
  (1 font-lock-type-face t)
  (2 font-lock-type-face t))))
```

Again, '1`and`2` select the corresponding subexpressions.

**Please note:**  The regexes for the typenames do not perfectly conform to C++ syntax.  For example, emacs will happily highlight nonsense like `sizeof(int * 32)`.

Also, my solution doesn't take into account the problem Pavel mentioned in the comment on your question; that you could also use `sizeof` on variables, which would need different highlighting.  I don't think this possible, short of implementing a complete C parser in the font lock code.